# Map function and iterables in python 3.6

Tags: functional-programming, generator, python-3.6, iterable

I've inherited a piece of code that I need to run somewhere else than the original place with some minor changes. I am trying to `map` a list of strings to something that applies a function to each element of that list using python 3.6 (a language I am not familiar with).

I would like to use `map` not list comprehension, but now I doubt this is possible.

In the following example I've tried a combination of `for` loops, `yield` (or not), and `next(...)` or not, but I am not able to make the code working as expected.

I would like to see the print:

```
AAA! xxx 
Found: foo
Found: bar
```

each time the counter `xxx` modulo `360` is `0` (zero).

I understand the `map` function does not execute the code, so then I need to do something to "apply" that function to each element of the input list.

However I am not able to make this thing work. This documentation https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#map and https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/functional.html#iterators do not help that much, I went through it and I think at least one of the commented bits below (`# <python code>`) should have worked. I am not an experienced python developer and I think I am missing some gotchas about the syntax/conventions of python 3.6 regarding iterators/generators.

```
issue_counter = 0

def foo_func(serious_stuff):
    # this is actually a call to a module to send an email with the "serious_stuff"
    print("Found: {}".format(serious_stuff))

def report_issue():
    global issue_counter
    # this actually executes once per minute (removed the logic to run this fast)
    while True:
        issue_counter += 1
        # every 6 hours (i.e. 360 minutes) I would like to send emails
        if issue_counter % 360 == 0:
            print("AAA! {}".format(issue_counter))
            # for stuff in map(foo_func, ["foo", "bar"]):
                # yield stuff
                # stuff()
                # print(stuff)
            iterable_stuff = map(foo_func, ["foo", "bar"])
            for stuff in next(iterable_stuff):
                # yield stuff
                print(stuff)

report_issue()
```

I get lots of different errors/unexpected behaviors of that `for` loop when running the script:

- not printing anything when I call `print(...)`
- `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`
- `AttributeError: 'map' object has no attribute 'next'`
- `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`
- Printing what I am expecting interleaved by `None`, e.g.:

> ```
> AAA! 3047040
> Found: foo
> None
> Found: bar
> None
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the call to `next(iterable_thingy)` actually invokes the mapped function.

Knowing the length of the input list when mapping it to generate the iterable, means we know how many times we have to invoke the `next(iterable_thingy)`, so the function `report_issue` (in my previous example) runs as expected when defined like this:

```
def report_issue():
    global issue_counter
    original_data = ["foo", "bar"]
    # this executes once per minute
    while True:
        issue_counter += 1
        # every 6 hours I would like to send emails
        if issue_counter % 360 == 0:
            print("AAA! {}".format(issue_counter))

            iterable_stuff = map(foo_func, original_data)
            for idx in range(len(original_data)):
                next(iterable_stuff)
```

To troubleshoot this iterable stuff I found useful running ipython (an interactive REPL) to check the type and documentation of the generated iterable, like this:

```
In [2]: def foo_func(serious_stuff):
    ...:     # this is actually a call to a module to send an email with the "serious_stuff"
    ...:     print("Found: {}".format(serious_stuff))    ...: 

In [3]: iterable_stuff = map(foo_func, ["foo", "bar"])

In [4]: iterable_stuff? 
Type:        map 
String form: <map object at 0x7fcdbe8647b8> 
Docstring:   
map(func, *iterables) --> map object

Make an iterator that computes the function using arguments from 
each of the iterables.  Stops when the shortest iterable is exhausted.

In [5]: next(iterable_stuff) Found: foo

In [6]: bar_item = next(iterable_stuff) Found: bar

In [7]: bar_item? 
Type:        NoneType 
String form: None 
Docstring:   <no docstring>

In [8]:
```